# set image nonzero pixel value to 1 and others to 0

Tags: image

I tried to use ImageApply and Boole function, but I still don't get the result I want.

I want all pixels in my image whose value larger than 0, it should be set to 1. And leave the rest unchanged.

Below is my code, can anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance!

```
img = ImageResize[Import["D:\\test.jpg"], {128, 128}];
ImageApply[{#, Boole[# > 0]} &, img]
```

Comment: How about `Binarize[img, 0]`?

Comment: That command is what I want, thanks a lot!